# Airline does not display correctly unless I source _vimrc

Tags: vimrc, plugin-airline

I have `airline` plugin installed with pathogen.

It displays `<bf><bf>` etc instead of showing normal characters. If I source my `_vimrc`, `airline` displays everything normally. I sometimes have to source twice. It used to work with no problems but recently I uninstalled Vim then installed a 64bit version (unofficial) and then uninstalled the latter and reinstalled vim74 32bit version (windows).

Here is my `_vimrc`:

```
set nocompatible
set maxcombine=6  
set autochdir
set backspace=2
set encoding=utf-8
set guifont=Hack:h9
set shiftwidth=3
set smartcase
set autoindent
set cindent
set smartindent 
set number numberwidth=4 relativenumber
set noerrorbells
set hlsearch
set hidden
set nobackup
set history=1000
set noswapfile
set guioptions-=T
set guitablabel=%t
set laststatus=2
set tabstop=3
set background=light


hi Search guifg=red guibg=yellow 

execute pathogen#infect()

syntax on
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on

colorscheme solarized 

let g:solarized_italic=0
let g:solarized_bold=0
let g:solarized_contrast="normal"

let g:airline_powerline_font=1
if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

 "airline symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = ''
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ''


autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.c,*.cpp,*.h,*.cxx,*.hpp,*.C,*.cc,*.cp,*.H,*.hxx set filetype=cpp nowrap
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.java set filetype=java nowrap
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.html,*.html,*.htm5,*.html5 set filetype=html nowrap
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.mysql,*.sql  set filetype=mysql nowrap

inoremap <c-u> <esc>viwU<esc>i
nnoremap - ddp
nnoremap <leader>ev :edit $MYVIMRC<cr>
nnoremap <leader>sv :source $MYVIMRC<cr>
nnoremap <leader>p "+p
nnoremap <leader>sd :nohl<cr>:nohl<cr>
nnoremap <leader>u kA<cr>
nnoremap <leader>[ <c-w>W
nnoremap <leader>] <c-w>w
```

I'm using the following plugins with pathogen:

- autocomplpop
- nerdtree
- nerdcommenter
- vim-airline
- vim-airline-themes
- vim-colors-solarized

For better understanding my problem, here are some screenshots:

Before sourcing `_vimrc`:
[image: Before...]

After sourcing `_vimrc`:
[image: After...]

New stuff:
An extremely weird thing:

moving `colorscheme solarized` below `let g:` etc makes sourcing `_vimrc` *once* enough to display `airline` correctly. Before that I used to source twice.

Comment: AAA I need some answers!

Comment: Hello and welcome to our site. Please note that all users here are volunteers and help you at their own convenience. Please give it some time for our user base to see your question as we are from all different timezones. There is also no guarantee that we will be able to solve your problem. All that being said, as a first step make sure there are no other vimrc files in any of the other possible directories that vim searches. Se `:h _vimrc` for a comprehensive list. And on that topic vim on Windows will also try to use a `.vimrc` if a `_vimrc` cannot be found.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem.

Add this to your `_vimrc`

```
scriptencoding utf-8
```